# Rellenar un JTextArea con un Array

Tags: java, java-swing

Necesito añadir los elementos de un array (en forma de lista) dentro de un JTextArea.

Adjunto un poco del código:

```
public class Estadisticas extends JFrame {

    JTextArea texto;

public Estadisticas() {
        this.setTitle("Estadísticas");
        JFrame marco = new JFrame("Estadísticas");
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(null);

        texto = new JTextArea(2, 2);
        texto.setBounds(10, 10, 200, 500);
        texto.setLineWrap(true);
        texto.setWrapStyleWord(true);

        panel.add(texto);

        marco.add(panel);
        marco.setSize(700, 700);
        marco.setVisible(true);
        marco.setResizable(false);
        marco.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        }        
}
```

Lo que necesito es hacer un array de 30 posiciones que contenga números generados aleatoriamente (entre 1 y 100), para ello hice lo siguiente:

```
int[] vector = new int[30];
        
        for (int i = 0; i < vector.length; i++) {
            int nums = (int) (Math.random() * 100 + 1);
            vector[i] = nums;
}
```

Posteriormente tengo que rellenar el JTextArea con los números generados en el array en forma de lista, algo así:

[image: Imagen De Ejemplo:]

Básicamente necesito saber cómo añadir el array con el formato de lista al JTextArea :)

Comment: en buen plan si es una lista por que no rellenar un JList?

Comment: Pues así lo solicitó el problema jeje

Comment: y que has intentado?

Comment: te recomiendo leer el articulo [Te he votado negativamente porque no intentaste nada](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2874/)

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar el método `append()` para agregar cada valor del array mediante la iteracion + un salto de linea`(\n)` el cual ara el efecto de lista

Ejemplo

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;

public class MostrarArray extends JFrame{
    private JTextArea area;
    private JButton btMostrar;
    private int[] vector = new int[30];
    public MostrarArray() {
        llenarArray();
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(new PanelArea(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        setTitle("Estadisticas");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);
    }
    private void llenarArray() {
        for (int i = 0; i < vector.length; i++) {
            int nums = (int) (Math.random() * 100 + 1);
            vector[i] = nums;
        }
    }
    private class PanelArea extends JPanel {
        public PanelArea() {
            area = new JTextArea(12, 12);
            add(area);
            setBorder(BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(
                    BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(25,30,25,30),
                    BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Numero aleatorios")));
                    for (int j = 0; j < vector.length; j++) {
                        area.append(vector[j] + "\n");
                    }
            }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new MostrarArray();
    }
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]